# Cancelar AsyncTask ao escolher outro item do menu com Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, asynctask, navigation-drawer

## O Problema

Estou desenvolvendo um app que possui um menu de navegação lateral (`Navigation Drawer`) conforme a figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O carregamento de alguns itens desse menu requer uma requisição a Internet. Aqui nesse ponto tudo funciona perfeitamente. Ao ser escolhido o item de menu com a essa característica executo uma AsyncTask que realiza a requisição, recupera e atualiza a informação na View. Porém se eu escolher um outro item de menu sem que esta AsyncTask tenha sido finalizada é criada uma situação que invalida todo o tratamento realizado no callback da AsyncTask e resulta em falha no aplicativo.

Diante do problema relatado acima, quero realizar o cancelamento da execução da AsyncTask quando outra opção do menu for escolhida. **Como implementar este cancelamento de forma adequada?**

---

## Código de implementação dos itens citados

#### Implementação do Menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    ...

    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FavoritosFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_favoritos);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ReclamacaoFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_reclamacoes);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ConfiguracoesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_configuracoes);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

}
```

#### Execução da AsyncTask

```
public class FavoritosFragment extends ListFragment {

    public FavoritosFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        new LinhaFavoritaTask(this).execute();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você cancelar a `AsyncTask`, deve chamar o método `cancel()` da mesma.

Deve ter um método responsável por chamar `cancel()` no seu fragmento (digamos que esse método se chame `cancelarCarregamentoDeDados()`) e esse método deve ser público, pois será chamado de fora do fragmento. De preferência esse método deve fazer parte do contrato do fragmento, isto é, o fragmento deve implementar uma interface que contenha esse método ou então estender um fragmento abstrato que obrigue suas subclasses a implementarem esse método (no código estou dando preferência à segunda opção). Se o seu fragmento já estende `ListFragment`, você deve deixar de estender `ListFragment` e implementar na mão as funcionalidades que ele oferece para tratar listas, para assim poder estender o fragmento abstrato. Minha sugestão é que esse fragmento abstrato se chame `ContentFragment` ou algo parecido, pois representa um fragmento que ocupa a área principal da tela (isto é, que pode ser adicionado ao `R.id.container_body`).

**ContentFragment:**

```
public abstract class ContentFragment extends Fragment {
    public abstract void cancelarCarregamentoDeDados();
}
```

**FavoritosFragment:**

```
public class FavoritosFragment extends ContentFragment {

    private LinhaFavoritaTask mTask;

    ...

    @Override
    public void cancelarCarregamentoDeDados() {
        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            mTask.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Para poder chamar esse método a partir da `Activity` (que deve ser a ponte entre os fragmentos, em vez de um se comunicar diretamente com o outro), a `Activity` precisa ter uma referência para o fragmento. A melhor forma de fazer isso é fazendo a `Activity` ter um atributo `mCurrentContentFragment` de tipo `ContentFragment` e um método público `setCurrentContentFragment(ContentFragment)`:

**Host:**

```
public interface Host {
    public abstract void setCurrentContentFragment(ContentFragment fragment);
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Host, ... {

    private ContentFragment mCurrentContentFragment = null;

    ...

    @Override
    public void setCurrentContentFragment(ContentFragment fragment) {
        this.mCurrentContentFragment = fragment;
    }

    ...
}
```

O método `setCurrentContentFragment()` deve ser chamado pelo próprio fragmento dentro do método `onStart()` do fragmento (de preferência do fragmento abstrato `ContentFragment`) assim:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Host activity = (Host)getActivity();
    activity.setCurrentContentFragment(this);
}
```

(Note que para evitar um acoplamento desnecessário entre o fragmento e a classe `MainActivity`, o método `setCurrentContentFragment()` deve idealmente pertencer a uma interface, digamos `Host`, que é implementada pela `Activity`).

Dessa forma o próprio ciclo de vida do fragmento sendo trocado (*replaced*) na tela se encarrega de atualizar a variável `mCurrentContentFragment`.

Feito tudo isso, sempre que você clicar em um item do Navigation Drawer pode antes de trocar o fragmento novo cancelar o carregamento do atual assim:

```
   if (fragment != null) {

        if (mCurrentContentFragment != null) {
            mCurrentContentFragment.cancelarCarregamentoDeDados();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Comment: Piovezan, sua solução é ótima! Funcionou perfeitamente. Resolvi não abrir mão das simplicidades do uso de ListFragment e para isso desmembrei um pouco sua solução para atender minha necessidade, mas em essência é a mesma solução. Vou postar aqui para constar e para que seja uma alternativa a quem quiser continuar utilizando a listagem com ListFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Este post tem como objetivo descrever as adaptações que foram feitas com base na resposta do **@Piovezan** usadas para solucionar o meu problema.

De modo geral utilizei em essência a solução postada por ele aqui. Contudo, não segui a sugestão abaixo:

> Se o seu fragmento já estende ListFragment, você deve deixar de
>   estender ListFragment e implementar na mão as funcionalidades que ele
>   oferece para tratar listas, para assim poder estender o fragmento
>   abstrato.

Por razões de conveniência continuei a estender os fragmentos que apresentam uma listagem a partir de `ListFragment`. Resolvi proceder dessa forma pelas facilidades oferecidas por esta classe ao se trabalhar com listagem de dados.

## Resumindo a solução adaptada

Foram criadas duas classes abstratas usadas por meus fragmentos. Uma específica para os fragmentos que utilizam listagem, que estende `ListFragment`. E outra mais genérica como o sugerido na resposta do **@Piovezan**. Essas classes contém por padrão a implementação do método `onStart()`. Outra mudança é que método de cancelamento da operação da `AsyncTask` foi incluído em uma interface. Portanto, minhas classes abstratas implementam um contrato que prevê o cancelamento de uma `AsyncTask`.

## Implementação

#### Classe de uso genérico para um Fragment

```
public abstract class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements TaskCancelable {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Host activity = (Host) getActivity();
        activity.seCurrentFragment(this);
    }
}
```

#### Classe de uso específico para um ListFragment

```
public abstract class ListContentFragment extends ListFragment implements TaskCancelable {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Host activity = (Host) getActivity();
        activity.seCurrentFragment(this);
    }
}
```

#### Contrato usado no cancelamento da AsyncTask

```
public interface TaskCancelable {
    void cancelTaskOperation();
}
```

#### Exemplo de um fragmento que utiliza ListFragment

```
public class FavoritosFragment extends ListContentFragment {

    private LinhaFavoritaTask task;

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        task = new LinhaFavoritaTask(this);
        task.execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelTaskOperation() {
        if (task != null && task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

#### A classe principal: responsável pelo carregamento do menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Host, FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private TaskCancelable mCurrentContentFragment = null;

    ...

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FavoritosFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_favoritos);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ReclamacaoFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_reclamacoes);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ConfiguracoesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_configuracoes);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            if (mCurrentContentFragment != null) {
                mCurrentContentFragment.cancelTaskOperation();
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void seCurrentFragment(TaskCancelable fragment) {
        this.mCurrentContentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

.